# How can I access a Class created with DI from a class not created with DI?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

**Preface** - we have an old service that we need to upkeep and occasionally modify. Its architecture is not good, and it is a mammoth, but since we hope to deprecate it eventually my company does not want to currently fix its architecture.

**Question**:
I have a class `MS`. I need to change one of its methods so that instead of calling HTTP directly, it will do so via another existing class, `AEO`. `AEO` inherits from abstract class `EC`,  has several fields it receives by means of DI, and is set up to be received by DI as well.

`MS` is not created via DI. Rather, the program.cs file that calls the method that adds DI, it creates a new instance of `MS`, manually passing its necessary parameters in.

How can I access `AEO` from within `MS`? If I just create `new AEO(...)` I will have an issue with passing the DI parameters which I do not have. If I just declare the Interface/Indexer as I would with normal DI, then upon creating `new MS(...)` I will have an issue of lacking the parameter to pass in to the constructor.

How can I make this work? Is it possible?

TIA

EDIT:

The way that `AEO` is declared with DI is thus:

```
builder.RegisterType<AEO>().Keyed<EC>(MCType.AEO)
                .SingleInstance().WithAttributeFiltering();
```

Comment: Since you are manually creating `MS` in the program class, and `AEO` is composed by (supposedly) the  DI Container, why don't you resolve `AEO` from the container when creating `MS`?

Comment: Something like: `var aeo = container.Resolve<IAeo>();`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes that looks like an interesting direction - could you elaborate?

Comment: You must find the DI container and let it resolve AEO. It will automatically inject the required DI parameters. See also [Named and Keyed Services](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Oliver Jacot-Descombes` comment, I found a working solution.

Before calling `new  MS(...)` I used reflection to get an instance of AEO.

```
               aeo = container.ResolveKeyed<EC>(MCType.AEO) as AEO;
```

and then passed `aeo` in to the `new MS(...,aeo)`

Answer (score 0):

**answer edited 15-Dec-2022**

Whenever I've had to perform this kind of refactoring in the past I've approached it from a different angle.

In order to mitigate risk the first step is to introduce your old service to the dependency injection process.

This will allow you to introduce replacement services, again using DI as you replace functionality.

Thus, you create an interface, `IMS` from `MS`, register that with your DI Container and then change your calling code to no longer work with a concrete instance of `MS` but `IMS` allowing the DI container to do its work.

Let us assume, for arguments sake that `IMS` is defined as:

```
interface IMS
{
    public FunctionOne();
    public HTTPFunction();
}
```

so that `MS` now implements that interface e.g.,

```
class MS : IMS
{
    public FunctionOne()
    {
         //Do some work
    }

    public HTTPFunction()
    {
         //Make some HTTP calls
    }
}
```

So you register `MS` interface (`IMS`) with DI container something like:

```
Container.Register<IMS, MS>("OldMS");
```

Thus you change in `program.cs` from

```
var msInstance = new MS();
```

to

```
var msInstance = Container.Resolve<IMS>("OldMS");
```

Testing should show that the program behaviour has not changed.

Next you wish to introduce `AEO` functionality for the one call in `MS`.

> AEO inherits from abstract class EC, has several fields it receives by means of DI, and is set up to be received by DI as well.

You fail to mention whether `AEO` implements any additional methods or properties to those that it inherits from `EC` so I'll assume that it's registered with an interface `IAEO` e.g.,

```
Container.Register<IAEO, AEO>();
```

If not then please interpolate where necessary.

Next we create a wrapper class around `MS` functionality that implements the `IMS` interface e.g.,

```
class MSTwo : IMS
{
    private IMS oldMs;
    private IAEO aeo;
    
    public MSTwo()
    {
        oldMS = Container.Resolve<IMS>("OldMS");
        aeo = Container.Resolve<IAEO>();
    }
    public FunctionOne()
    {
        oldMS.FunctionOne();
    }
    public HTTPFunction()
    {
        aeo.SomeFunction();
    }
}
```

This class you register with your DI Container e.g.,

```
Container.Register<IMS, MSTwo>("NewMS");
```

and it can then be resolved within `program.cs`

```
var msInstance = Container.Resolve<IMS>("NewMS");
```

**Note:** In the above examples, for simplicity, I've omitted any reference to DI through constructors, their registration with the DI Container nor there resolution at runtime as the syntax is often DI Container dependent.

Comment: Hey, I am a little confused by what you are suggesting here. Currently AEO has a method that it overrides from EC, an abstract class. If I make an IAEO, do I not then have issues resolving the method? How does it know if it is from IAEO or from EC? I do not have the flexibility to change EC since there are 2 other classes that inherit from it as well. Also I am not clear on how this solves the issue the new MS(..) that occues in the program.cs file - if I have it implementing IMS, it does not answer the current usage

Comment: Also want to point you towards the preface of the question - where the company is not currently interested in investing the time to reconstruct the architecture

Comment: Please see my edited answer. I didn't mean to suggest that `EC` nor `MS` is changed